# openTSDB query for metrics which dont have a tag

Tags: opentsdb

is there any way to query for metric values that dont have a tag?for example metric1 is logged with tag1, tag2 or with only tag1.How can i get all the graphs that have just tag1nd not the one that have both tag1 nd tag2?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a value for `tag2` (even just `tag2=*`), then only data points that have that tag will be returned.

Comment: I know.But i want the ones WITHOUT that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your question (if I have understood it as, what you meant) - you have a timeseries:

```
{metric: metric1, timestamp: 123467789, value: 32, tags:{tag1:foo, tag2:bar}}
```

To query:

```
/api/query??start=1h-ago&m=sum:metric1{tag1=foo,tag2=bar}
```

But what you want is the data points - only with `tag1`:

```
{metric: metric1, timestamp: 123467789, value: 32, tag1:foo}
```

**Answer**:

I didn't find any solution - but have a suggestion. You can make it work by introducing a third tag i.e. `tag3` set it to 1 in case of no `tag2`:

```
{metric: metric1, timestamp: 123467789, value: 32, tags:{tag1:foo, tag3:bar}}
```

Now you can query only the points with `tag1` (no `tag2`):

```
/api/query??start=1h-ago&m=sum:metric1{tag1=foo,tag3=1}
```

**PS** Or you can specify a fixed value for `tag2` i.e. 0 in case of no value.

Answer (score 0):

While this wasn't possible at the time you asked, there is the [explicitTags](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/filters.html#explicit-tags) flag since version 2.3, which does exactly what you want:

> 2. For metrics with varying tags, this can be used to avoid aggregating
>      time series that should not be included in the final result.

Not related to you question, but It can also be used to optimize the query, according to the docs:

> As of 2.3 and later, if you know all of the tag keys for a given
>   metric query latency can be improved greatly by using the explicitTags
>   feature. This flag has two benefits:
>
> 1. For metrics that have a high cardinality, the backend can switch to a
>      more efficient query to fetch a smaller subset of data from storage.
>      (Particularly in 2.4)